# Vue dynamic routes - display user details from another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have user list inside UserList.vue component. I would like to display each user details inside SigleUser.vue component (subpage). How can i do it the easy way?

User details is contained in the UserList.vue component. When I click on a link for a specific user, I would like to go to his profile

Router paths: /user/1, /user/2, /user/3 etc.

**UserList.vue:**

```
<template>
  <v-list two-line>
    <template v-for="(user) in users">
      <v-list-item
          :key="user.username"
      >
        <router-link
            :to="`user/${user.id}`"
        >
          <v-list-item-avatar>
            <v-img :src="user.avatar"></v-img>
          </v-list-item-avatar>
        </router-link>

        <v-list-item-content>
          <router-link
              :to="`user/${user.id}`"
          >
          <span class="name">
            {{ user.name }}
          </span>
            <span class="username">
            {{ user.usernaname }}
          </span>
          </router-link>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </template>
  </v-list>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    users: [
      {
        id: 1,
        username: 'johndoe',
        name: 'John Doe',
        avatar: require('@/assets/images/john-doe.png'),
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        username: 'bobdoe',
        name: 'Bob Doe',
        avatar: require('@/assets/images/bob-doe.png'),
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        username: 'annedoe',
        name: 'Anne Doe',
        avatar: require('@/assets/images/anne-doe.png'),
      },
    ],

  }),
}
</script>
```

**SingleUser.vue (Single user profile):**

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ user.name }}</h1>
  <h2>{{ user.username }}</h2>
  <v-img :src="user.avatar"></v-img>
</template>

<script>

</script>
```

**router.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
  path: '/',
  name: 'Home',
  component: Home
  },
  {
  path: '/users',
  name: 'Users',
  component: () => import('../views/UserList.vue')
  },

  {
  path: '/user/:id',
  name: 'User',
  component: () => import('../views/SingleUser.vue')
  },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

Comment: Since the route only receives the user ID - the SingleUser component will have to either fetch the user details from your API (using the provided user ID) or look it up into Vuex (if you keep your UserList data in Vuex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example application in my Vue 2 CLI sandbox app.  Normally I would retrieve users and user details from an API, but in my sample app, I used Vuex to store and retrieve users. I also used a standard `<ul>` instead of `<v-list>`, since I haven't used Vuetify (another day), and left out the images.  But the routing implementation should work in your application.

UserList.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="user-list">
    <h3>User List</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul>
          <li v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'User', params: { id: user.id }}">{{ user.name }}</router-link>
          </li>
        </ul>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'UserList',
    data() {
      return {
        users: [
          {
            id: 1,
            username: 'johndoe',
            name: 'John Doe',
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            username: 'bobdoe',
            name: 'Bob Doe',
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            username: 'annedoe',
            name: 'Anne Doe',
          },
        ]
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.$store.commit('initUsers', this.users);
    }
  }
</script>
```

SingleUser.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="single-user">
    <h3>Single User</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>{{ user.name }}</h4>
        <h4>{{ user.username }}</h4>
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'Users' }">Back</router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'SingleUser',
    props: {
      id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      }
    },
    computed: {
      user() {
        return this.$store.getters.getUser(this.id);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

/router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import UserList from '@/components/stackoverflow/router-link/UserList'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/users'
  },
  {
    path: '/users',
    name: 'Users',
    component: UserList
  },
  {
    path: '/user/:id',
    name: 'User',
    component: () => import('@/components/stackoverflow/router-link/SingleUser'),
    props: true
  },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

/store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    users: []
  },
  getters: {
    getUser: (state) => (id) => {
      return state.users.find( user => user.id === id);
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    initUsers(state, newUsers) {
      state.users = newUsers;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great :)
But I noticed that direct URL is not working for '/user/:id', e.g. '/user/1', '/user/2' etc. (a blank page is displayed). Only router link click works. The parent direct URLs works fine, e.g. '/users'. Could you please help me solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'direct url'.  Routed link click works.  Can you be more specific (technical) as to what doesn't work?

Comment: When I want to go directly to the user's page (SingleUser.vue) using the URL, I get a blank page. This error occurs when I refresh the page or press enter in the browser bar. However, when I click the link in the UserList.vue (directly on the page with the list of users), a single profile is displayed correctly. To view the user's profile again (or other profile), I have to go back to the users list and click on the router link again. I have no idea why this is happening because the parent routes works. I have a 404 page set up, but in this case (user/:id) it shows a blank page.

Comment: A blank page, i.e. a page without the SingleUser.vue component (other components are displayed)

Comment: You are thinking in terms of browser behavior with traditional client/server, when changing the address in the browser address bar send a standard HTTP GET request (not just an AJAX request) to the server, which then renders and responds with a new complete HTML page.  Vue and other browser client frameworks don't work that way.  I know that if you refresh the browser, it completely re-initializes the Vue application.  So my understanding is that you have to navigate via router links for the app to work.  I'm not an expert though, so searching may find you a better explanation.  Vue Help Forum